# How to force a setter bar of Animate to autorun?

Tags: plotting, animation, plot-themes

I have an animate as below:-

```
Animate[plot[i], {i, {1, 2, 3}, ControlType -> SetterBar}, AnimationRunning -> True]
```

As you can see, I am trying to force it to autorun by adding `AnimationRunning -> True`. But it still won't autorun.

How can I force it to do so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second control with `AppearanceElements -> None` attached to the same variable:

```
Animate[plot[i], {{i, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3}, 
     AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRunning -> True, AppearanceElements -> None},
 {i, {1, 2, 3}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Manipulate` using the same controls with the option `AppearanceElements -> None` instead of `Animate`

```
Manipulate[plot[i], 
 Row[{Control[{i, {1, 2, 3}, SetterBar}], 
   Control[{{i, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3}, Animator, 
     AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRunning -> True, 
     AppearanceElements -> None}]}], AppearanceElements -> None, 
 ContentSize -> {200, 200}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]